SQLAlchemy Many-to-Many using PostgreSQL's on_conflict_do_update doesn't get committed
I'm trying to use a many-to-many relationship in SQLAlchemy with PostgreSQL.  I want to take advantage of the on_conflict_do_update, so I have to use insert statements instead of creating an ORM object, adding it to the session, and committing.
I've discovered that when an object is created this way, adding a many-to-many relationship with thing.relationship.append doesn't work.  I.e. when you commit, there's no new row in the association table.
I've reproduced the problem below with tables B and C (and BC to join them).  I noted the way to make the relationship work, but you can't run the code twice because it'll lead to a UniqueConstraint error.
from typing import List
from sqlalchemy import Column, create_engine, ForeignKey, String, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship, Session
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass
bc_table = Table(
    "bc",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("b_id", ForeignKey("b.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), index=True, primary_key=True),
    Column("c_id", ForeignKey("c.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), index=True, primary_key=True)
)
class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    foo: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, unique=True)
    cs: Mapped[List["C"]] = relationship(back_populates="bs", secondary=bc_table)
class C(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'c'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    bar: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, unique=True)
    bs: Mapped[List["B"]] = relationship(back_populates="cs", secondary=bc_table)


engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:hunter2@localhost:5432/replica')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():
    # I have to use an insert to take advantage of `on_conflict_do_update`
    set_ = {'foo': 1}
    b_stmt = insert(B).values(set_)
    b_stmt = b_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(index_elements=[B.foo], set_=set_)
    cro = session.execute(b_stmt)
    b = B(id=cro.inserted_primary_key[0], **set_)

    set_ = {'bar': 1}
    c_stmt = insert(C).values(set_)
    c_stmt = c_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(index_elements=[C.bar], set_=set_)
    cro = session.execute(c_stmt)
    c = C(id=cro.inserted_primary_key[0], **set_)

    # Try to create a many-to-many relationship entry between b and c. 
    c.bs.append(b)

    ## The easy way would be to do this, but I can't because I need to use on_conflict_do_update
    # b = B(foo=1)
    # c = C(bar=1)
    # c.bs.append(b)
    # session.add_all([b, c])

    session.commit()


How can I make c.bs.append get committed?  Is the solution just to check whether the bs or cs exists and only create it via b = ...; c = ...; session.add_all([b,c])?  I'd prefer the atomicity of on_conflict_do_update.

I think these docs are what you want: using-returning-with-upsert-statements
Notes:

use returning(B) to get an ORM object back, sqlalchemy should be smart enough to get the id and other columns
use execution_options={"populate_existing": True} to make sure any B or C in the session will be updated (does not seem to apply here but that might depend on your actual code)
use scalars() to avoid getting 1-tuples back, ie. [(B(),) (B(),), ...]
use first() to just get the single result you inserted or updated
at the point where c.bs.append(b) is called both the c and b should be ORM object in the session, whereas before I think the problem was they were not known to the session so commit did nothing.

Untested example usage
with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():
    set_ = {'foo': 1}
    b_stmt = insert(B).returning(B).values(set_)
    b_stmt = b_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(index_elements=[B.foo], set_=set_)
    b = session.scalars(b_stmt, execution_options={"populate_existing": True}).first()

    set_ = {'bar': 1}
    c_stmt = insert(C).returning(C).values(set_)
    c_stmt = c_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(index_elements=[C.bar], set_=set_)
    c = session.scalars(c_stmt, execution_options={"populate_existing": True}).first()

    # Try to create a many-to-many relationship entry between b and c. 
    c.bs.append(b)

    session.commit()

